# How to align columns where label overflows

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, lightning-design-system

How to adjust the alignment of columns when the label overflows?

[image]

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-p-top_x-small slds-form_horizontal slds-form ">
                    <div class="slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--x-small" >
                            <label for="BillingCity" class="slds-text-title">Billing City</label>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="BillingCity" variant="label-hidden"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--x-small" >
                            <label for="BillingState" class="slds-text-title">Billing State/Province</label>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="BillingState" variant="label-hidden"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="slds-size_4-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--x-small" >
                            <label for="ShippingCity" class="slds-text-title">Shipping City</label>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="ShippingCity" variant="label-hidden"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="slds-size_2-of-12 slds-p-horizontal--x-small" >
                            <label for="ShippingState" class="slds-text-title">Shipping State/Province</label>
                            <lightning:inputField fieldName="ShippingState" variant="label-hidden"/>
                     </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure on what is the problem you have with your code, one of them is you are using a deprecated class `slds-p-horizontal--x-small` that should be `slds-p-horizontal_x-small` (Few years ago Salesforce had replaced double dashes in classes with an underscore as it gave problems with code comments in HTML).

Using the SLDS classes for horizontal form in your own markup is nice but this can be achieved in a simpler way with the use of [`lightning:layout`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:layout/example) base component, here is an example:

```html
<lightning:layout>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small">
        <label for="BillingCity" class="slds-text-title">Billing City</label>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="BillingCity" variant="label-hidden"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="2" padding="around-small">
        <label for="BillingState" class="slds-text-title">Billing State/Province</label>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="BillingState" variant="label-hidden"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small">
        <label for="ShippingCity" class="slds-text-title">Shipping City</label>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="ShippingCity" variant="label-hidden"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="2" padding="around-small">
        <label for="ShippingState" class="slds-text-title">Shipping State/Province</label>
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="ShippingState" variant="label-hidden"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

[image]

Comment: hi thank you so much for answering I tried doing the layout item but still the same the label still over flow

Comment: @mayan: your example in question doesn't illustrate the problem properly, please share minimal code with which we can replicate the problem.